# Is it possible to show all tags which I can use inside root element(in xml) in android studio?

Tags: android

While writing code in styles.xml it's takes a lot of time to look which tag could be used inside root-element. Is there some hotkeys to show all possible tags in drop-down list?

[We have tag **resources** and after pressing Ctrl + Space android studio writes 'No suggestions'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnxTu.png)

Comment: What do you mean by tag?

Comment: added photo to answer your question. it's available by pressing on link.

Comment: Are you completely new to android studio?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + whitespace (on Windows)

Otherwise refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html).